# Compute document access using computed field

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a following situation.

There are two document types:

---

**Parent**

Field Person - Name

---

**Child**

Field ParentNoteUNID - Text

Fields Name, Surname etc..- Text

---

I would like to compute access to Child document, so Child document could be edited by person included in Name field of Parent.

I tried to use Computed for display Authors field on Child document with following formula:

```
@Name([Canonicalize];@GetDocField(ParentNoteUNID;"Person"))
```

Field seems to be calculated, but access is not granted when document is opened.

Point is to grant access to document using computed field, without field recalculation on existing documents.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a computed for display field to control access, because they are not stored in the document on disk. They only exist in memory *after* someone opens the document. Enforcement of Reader and Author fields by the Notes APIs occurs *before* the document is actually opened.

If you want to change access, you will have to use a computed field, and you will have to do the recalculation for all of the affected documents. The Reader and Author fields have to be saved to disk in the NSF file before the APIs will honor them.

Comment: Ok, so I have to write an agent that updates all authors fields in Child documents?

Comment: Yes, and bear in mind that an agent won't automatically respect the fact that you set the field type on the form to Authors, so you will probably have to use ComputeWithForm in LotusScrpt or @Command([ViewRefreshFields] in a formula agent in order to assure that the fields you create or modify are set as Author fields instead of as ordinary text fields.